# how to load the pages in scrolling

Tags: javascript, php, css

here is my question 
i wanted to load some images in a table(load only some images in a page not load every images like first three rows) after scrolling load balance few images(next 3 rows) then again scrolling load next three rows

Is this possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for infinite scrolling like facebook. Whenever you scroll down to page it load another set (here 3 images) of records instead of full data.You can get it from below links:

1) https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll
2) http://jscroll.com/
3) http://plugins.jquery.com/infiniteScroll/

Comment: thank you very much second link is right...but i didnt gt a result in my prgm.. i dnt knw how to use that